# Determine whether or not a smaller image is within a screenshot?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, bots, image-recognition

I've started making a bot in Python. The objective of the bot is to read simple one-digit numbers off the screen then add them together. At the moment I know how I would get the screenshot. I'm stuck on the image recognition. I've looked into OpenCV Template Matching.

I've tried to get my head around how to do this for days.
The only code I've been able to write is at the bottom of the question.

For example what I'm trying to do is:
(In order)

1. It will grab a screenshot
2. It will run through comparing my images of numbers to the screenshot
3. Upon finding a matching image it will record a value to a variable.
4. Then it will move on to the next number.
5. It will repeat steps 1 - 3
6. It will add the to numbers together.

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy
from cv2 import cv
import PIL
from PIL import ImageGrab

print("Authentication")
print("Enter Password:")
entered = raw_input()
if entered == "hello":
    print("************Menu************")
    print("1: Quit")
    print("2: Start Bot")
    print("3: Settings")
    print("*" * 28)
    mode = input("")
    if mode == 1:
        print("Closing Answer Quick")
        import time
        time.sleep(3)
        quit
    elif mode == 2:
        import time
        print("Bot Initialize")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Getting Screen")
        time.sleep(3)

        screenimage = ImageGrab.grab()
        x = [1, "images\1.png", "images\2.png", "images\3.png", "images\4.png", "images\5.png", "images\6.png", "images\7.png", "images\8.png", "images\9.png"]
    ##Here is where the screen recognition code goes

    elif mode == 3:
        print("Settings")
    else:

        import time
        print("Incorrect Password")
        time.sleep(3)
        quit
```

Comment: If you are looking for template matching, visit this SOF : stackoverflow.com/questions/14486353/image-in-image-with-cvmatchtemplate-but-how/14487266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using OpenCV simply for academic purposes, I would recommend using OCR as a more simplistic approach to solving your number identification task. Here is a python library based on Tesseract which is maintained by Google as a leading OCR technology. It also has a numeric detection only setting.

http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/